# Can .dll's be automatically released with main executable?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, deployment, release, dynamic-library

Is there any way in Visual Studio or something else that allows the programmer to export the main executable with the dynamic libraries without the need to copy manually some important .dll's from system32 or somewhere else?
For example, OpenGL programs need (beside glut32.dll and opengl32.dll) msvcr100.dll to run.

Is there any **efficient** or **professional** way of deploying applications that use dynamic libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this in Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project:

1. Project - Properties - Prerequisites.
2. Project - Add - Merge Module.

The second way is more flexible and may be used for third-party merge modules, not included in Prerequisites dialog.

Of course, if you don't have Setup and Deployment project yet, create one for your application.